# When to use pthread_mutex_t

Tags: c++, pthreads, mutex

Can someone please explain in what scenario's it would be beneficial to use std::mutex vs pthread_mutex_t. I dont understand why we would ever use pthread_mutex_t. Thanks

Comment: @xaxxon AFAIK, you can use std::mutex and only use the pthread_specific stuff for things that are not available through the std:: thread api. The std:: api allows you to get a native thread handle for pthread stuff. Then, adapting the app to e.g. Windows would require less work and less #ifdefs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

std::mutex is just a thin wrapper around pthread_mutex on systems supporting pthreads.

In general, the operations on the std:: thread primitives are quite limited vs the native versions (pthreads or windows threads). If you don't need those features, you should always use the std:: versions, but if you do need the advanced features, then you have no choice but to use the native version.

[`native handle()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/native_handle) method exists for exactly this reason.

Answer (score 15):

The `pthread_mutex_t` is a POSIX solution (available for linux and other UNIX systems) that existed before c++11 introduced synchronisation primitives into the c++ library. You should use `std::mutex` now, amongst other things it is more cross-platform (can be used under Windows also).

Comment: *"linux-specific solution"* - it's a lot older and more widespread than that; being part of POSIX, it's been supported on UNIX systems as far back as I can remember (i.e. it was old 30 years ago), VMS and others too.

Answer (score 1):

`std::mutex` is from standard library, so if you use it your code will compile also on platforms where pthreads are not provided. For example under windows `std::mutex` uses native WinAPI mutex implementation.

Its best to always use `std::mutex`.

Comment: An additional advantage of std:: threading is that you can easily ues RAII, so it mixes much better with C++ exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

See pthread_mutexattr for an idea of the other flavors of POSIX mutexes available besides the default.  Though one of the main ones-- recursive vs. nonrecursive-- is available with std::recursive_mutex, this is not true for things like BSD priority ceilings, etc.